Kerberos Auth with JavaEE no longer working after upgrading Wildfly 15 to 26 using Elytron
I have a simple JavaEE Application running on my wildfly to authenticate users with kerberos. The user sends a request from the web application and receives the login JWT-Token. The beginning of the service class looks like this:
@Path("/")
@RequestScoped
@Transactional
public class AuthService {

    ...

    @Inject
    private SecurityContext securityContext;
    
    ...

    @GET
    @Path("/login")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + "; charset=UTF-8")
    @PermitAll
    public Response getAuthUser() throws InvalidLicenseException {

        JsonObjectBuilder json = Json.createObjectBuilder();
        try {
            if (securityContext == null) {
                json.add("securityContext", "securityContext is null");
                return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).entity(json.build()).build();
            }

            Principal principal = securityContext.getCallerPrincipal();
            if (principal == null) {
                json.add("principal", "getCallerPrincipal is null");
                return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).entity(json.build()).build();

...


When using the wildfly 15 with the module jboss:domain:security:2.0 it works perfectly fine and securityContext.getCallerPrincipal() returns the user that called. After upgrading the wildfly to 26 and using the wildfly:elytron:15.1 module the method getCallerPrincipal() returns null. Im using Java version 11.0.23.
I have migrated the configuration using this guide.
First the method always returned null, now my browser is asking me to enter a username and a password.
The following are the relevant parts of my standalone.xml:
System-properties:
    <system-properties>
        ...
        <property name="java.security.krb5.conf" value="C:\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\configuration\krb5.conf"/>
        <property name="sun.security.spnego.debug" value="true"/>
        <property name="sun.security.krb5.debug" value="true"/>
    </system-properties>

Elytron-Module:
<subsystem xmlns="urn:wildfly:elytron:15.1" final-providers="combined-providers" disallowed-providers="OracleUcrypto">
            <providers>
                <aggregate-providers name="combined-providers">
                    <providers name="elytron"/>
                    <providers name="openssl"/>
                </aggregate-providers>
                <provider-loader name="elytron" module="org.wildfly.security.elytron"/>
                <provider-loader name="openssl" module="org.wildfly.openssl"/>
            </providers>
            <audit-logging>
                <file-audit-log name="local-audit" path="audit.log" relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" format="JSON"/>
            </audit-logging>
            <security-domains>
                <security-domain name="ManagementDomain" default-realm="ManagementRealm" permission-mapper="default-permission-mapper">
                    <realm name="ManagementRealm" role-decoder="groups-to-roles"/>
                    <realm name="local" role-mapper="super-user-mapper"/>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="ApplicationDomain" default-realm="ApplicationRealm" permission-mapper="default-permission-mapper">
                    <realm name="ApplicationRealm" role-decoder="groups-to-roles"/>
                    <realm name="local"/>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="SPNEGODomain" default-realm="SPNEGO" permission-mapper="default-permission-mapper">
                    <realm name="SPNEGO" role-decoder="groups-to-roles"/>
                </security-domain>
            </security-domains>
            <security-realms>
                <identity-realm name="local" identity="$local"/>
                <properties-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
                    <users-properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" digest-realm-name="ApplicationRealm"/>
                    <groups-properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </properties-realm>
                <properties-realm name="ManagementRealm">
                    <users-properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" digest-realm-name="ManagementRealm"/>
                    <groups-properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </properties-realm>
                <properties-realm name="SPNEGO">
                    <users-properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" digest-realm-name="SPNEGODomain"/>
                    <groups-properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </properties-realm>
            </security-realms>
            <credential-security-factories>
                <kerberos-security-factory name="test-server" principal="HTTP/DEMO@*****.LOCAL" path="C:\wildfly-26.1.3.Final\standalone\configuration\NEWDEMO.keytab" debug="true"/>
            </credential-security-factories>
            <mappers>
                <simple-permission-mapper name="default-permission-mapper" mapping-mode="first">
                    <permission-mapping>
                        <principal name="anonymous"/>
                        <permission-set name="default-permissions"/>
                    </permission-mapping>
                    <permission-mapping match-all="true">
                        <permission-set name="login-permission"/>
                        <permission-set name="default-permissions"/>
                    </permission-mapping>
                </simple-permission-mapper>
                <constant-realm-mapper name="local" realm-name="local"/>
                <simple-role-decoder name="groups-to-roles" attribute="groups"/>
                <constant-role-mapper name="super-user-mapper">
                    <role name="SuperUser"/>
                </constant-role-mapper>
            </mappers>
            <permission-sets>
                <permission-set name="login-permission">
                    <permission class-name="org.wildfly.security.auth.permission.LoginPermission"/>
                </permission-set>
                <permission-set name="default-permissions">
                    <permission class-name="org.wildfly.extension.batch.jberet.deployment.BatchPermission" module="org.wildfly.extension.batch.jberet" target-name="*"/>
                    <permission class-name="org.wildfly.transaction.client.RemoteTransactionPermission" module="org.wildfly.transaction.client"/>
                    <permission class-name="org.jboss.ejb.client.RemoteEJBPermission" module="org.jboss.ejb-client"/>
                </permission-set>
            </permission-sets>
            <http>
                <http-authentication-factory name="management-http-authentication" security-domain="ManagementDomain" http-server-mechanism-factory="global">
                    <mechanism-configuration>
                        <mechanism mechanism-name="DIGEST">
                            <mechanism-realm realm-name="ManagementRealm"/>
                        </mechanism>
                    </mechanism-configuration>
                </http-authentication-factory>
                <http-authentication-factory name="application-http-authentication" security-domain="ApplicationDomain" http-server-mechanism-factory="global">
                    <mechanism-configuration>
                        <mechanism mechanism-name="BASIC">
                            <mechanism-realm realm-name="ApplicationRealm"/>
                        </mechanism>
                    </mechanism-configuration>
                </http-authentication-factory>
                <http-authentication-factory name="spnego-http-authentication" security-domain="SPNEGODomain" http-server-mechanism-factory="global">
                    <mechanism-configuration>
                        <mechanism mechanism-name="SPNEGO" credential-security-factory="test-server"/>
                    </mechanism-configuration>
                </http-authentication-factory>
                <provider-http-server-mechanism-factory name="global"/>
            </http>
            <sasl>
                <sasl-authentication-factory name="management-sasl-authentication" sasl-server-factory="configured" security-domain="ManagementDomain">
                    <mechanism-configuration>
                        <mechanism mechanism-name="JBOSS-LOCAL-USER" realm-mapper="local"/>
                        <mechanism mechanism-name="DIGEST-MD5">
                            <mechanism-realm realm-name="ManagementRealm"/>
                        </mechanism>
                    </mechanism-configuration>
                </sasl-authentication-factory>
                <sasl-authentication-factory name="application-sasl-authentication" sasl-server-factory="configured" security-domain="ApplicationDomain">
                    <mechanism-configuration>
                        <mechanism mechanism-name="JBOSS-LOCAL-USER" realm-mapper="local"/>
                        <mechanism mechanism-name="DIGEST-MD5">
                            <mechanism-realm realm-name="ApplicationRealm"/>
                        </mechanism>
                    </mechanism-configuration>
                </sasl-authentication-factory>
                <configurable-sasl-server-factory name="configured" sasl-server-factory="elytron">
                    <properties>
                        <property name="wildfly.sasl.local-user.default-user" value="$local"/>
                        <property name="wildfly.sasl.local-user.challenge-path" value="${jboss.server.temp.dir}/auth"/>
                    </properties>
                </configurable-sasl-server-factory>
                <mechanism-provider-filtering-sasl-server-factory name="elytron" sasl-server-factory="global">
                    <filters>
                        <filter provider-name="WildFlyElytron"/>
                    </filters>
                </mechanism-provider-filtering-sasl-server-factory>
                <provider-sasl-server-factory name="global"/>
            </sasl>
            <tls>
                <key-stores>
                    <key-store name="applicationKS">
                        <credential-reference clear-text="password"/>
                        <implementation type="JKS"/>
                        <file path="application.keystore" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                    </key-store>
                </key-stores>
                <key-managers>
                    <key-manager name="applicationKM" key-store="applicationKS" generate-self-signed-certificate-host="localhost">
                        <credential-reference clear-text="password"/>
                    </key-manager>
                </key-managers>
                <server-ssl-contexts>
                    <server-ssl-context name="applicationSSC" key-manager="applicationKM"/>
                </server-ssl-contexts>
            </tls>
            <policy name="jacc">
                <jacc-policy/>
            </policy>
        </subsystem>


Ive set the domains here, the keytab and the address to the kerberos server.
Undertow-Module:
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:12.0" default-server="default-server" default-virtual-host="default-host" default-servlet-container="default" default-security-domain="other" statistics-enabled="${wildfly.undertow.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}">
            <buffer-cache name="default"/>
            <server name="default-server">
                <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
                <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" ssl-context="applicationSSC" enable-http2="true"/>
                <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                    <http-invoker http-authentication-factory="application-http-authentication"/>
                </host>
            </server>
            <servlet-container name="default">
                <jsp-config/>
                <websockets/>
            </servlet-container>
            <application-security-domains>
                <application-security-domain name="jaspitest" security-domain="ApplicationDomain" enable-jaspi="true" integrated-jaspi="false"/>
                <application-security-domain name="other" security-domain="ApplicationDomain"/>
                <application-security-domain name="ApplicationSPNEGODomain" http-authentication-factory="spnego-http-authentication"/>
            </application-security-domains>
        </subsystem>

The JavaEE-Application configuration looks like this:
jboss-web.xml:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>ApplicationSPNEGODomain</security-domain>
    <jacc-star-role-allow>true</jacc-star-role-allow>
</jboss-web>


web.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.role.based.security</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Public</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/onlineStatus</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>All</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method-omission>OPTIONS</http-method-omission>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>*</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>SPNEGO</auth-method>
        <realm-name>SPNEGODomain</realm-name>
    </login-config>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </security-role>

</web-app>


If you need anymore information about the configuration let me know.
I tried using the standard configuration and adding the configuration according to this guide
I also tried this guide
With this configuration im only getting a popup to enter my username and password. In a different try I just received null from getCallerPrincipal(). It seems like the configuration is not set properly. Im expecting it to work just like my old wf15 setup.
The kerberos server is the same so I can confirm that it works with wf15.
Help would be much appreciated.
